# Hi am trying to add maven plugin to eclipse the following error can one help me out to solve this

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin 0.15.0.201207090124 (org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper.feature.feature.group 0.15.0.201207090124)
  Missing requirement: m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin 0.15.0.201207090124 (org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper 0.15.0.201207090124) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.jdt [1.1.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin 0.15.0.201207090124 (org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper.feature.feature.group 0.15.0.201207090124)
    To: org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper [0.15.0.201207090124]
```

Comment: It is looking for the `org.eclipse.m2e.jdt` plug-in which I think is part of the normal Eclipse maven (m2e) feature - do you have that installed?

Comment: No its not installing error message as i pasted above

Comment: even i tried through command mvn elcipse:eclipse it also not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a more recent version 0.15.0.201405280027 of org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper available from https://otto.takari.io/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-buildhelper/0.15.0/N/0.15.0.201405280027/